# How to enable ping for virtual machines running on Azure?

Tags: linux, windows, azure, redhat

I have two virtual hosts running on Azure. One is Windows 2008 and the second one is RedHat Linux.

I want to be able to ping those hosts (from my laptop which is outside of the Azure network).
How to do it?

I've already opened some port on these hosts. I can telnet to these ports. Yet I want to be able to ping the hosts since I want to know if they are alive, as well as knowing the latency time.

I've googled but I couldn't realize if it's possible to ping (or not) and how to.

Thank you

Comment: I guess you must be having a network where these VM reside. If the network is point to site configured, download the client package vpn, install it. Then you will be able to ping from your local machine

Comment: This really belongs on ServerFault, but I linked to the question which is nearly an exact duplicate (though you might not be able to view it due to your reputation). Essentially no ICMP support from outside of Azure.

Answer (score 2):

From this blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity/, you would need to use `port ping` instead of simple `ping` using tools like `psping`.

> Because the ICMP protocol is not permitted through the Azure load
>   balancer, you will notice that you are unable to ping an Azure VM from
>   the internet, and from within the Azure VM, you are unable to ping
>   internet locations.
>
> Testing from on-premises to the Azure VM shows the same behavior. The
>   ICMP traffic is blocked by the Azure load balancer and the ping
>   requests timeout. But if you instead do a port ping, they will succeed
>   (assuming the VM is running, isn’t blocking the port in the guest
>   firewall, and the port has a configured endpoint for the VM).